# is there any advice, to give value to key inside JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I'm trying to use alert to find out the value of the variable before the format changed to words, then there is error message about the index number in the array. it said :uncaught SyntaxError : unexpected Number which is this line bulan 1 januari

is there any advice, to give value to key in the array ?

```
$( function() {
$( "#pickyDate" ).datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});

local = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
bulan = [1=>'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei',  'Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember' ];

$('#getdate').datepicker()
.on("change", function () {    

 var today = new Date($('#getdate').datepicker('getDate'));
 var tanggal = today.getDate();
 var no_hari = today.getDay();
 var no_bulan = today.getMonth()+1; 
 var tahun = today.getFullYear(); 

 //alert(local[today.getDay()]);
 alert(tahun);
 //$('#wordsdate').val(local[today.getDay()]);


});
});
```

```js
$( function() {
$( "#pickyDate" ).datepicker({format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});

local = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
bulan = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni','Juli','Agustus','September','Oktober','November','Desember' ];

$('#getdate').datepicker()
.on("change", function () {    

 var today = new Date($('#getdate').datepicker('getDate'));
 var tanggal = today.getDate();
 var no_hari = today.getDay();
 var no_bulan = today.getMonth(); 
 var tahun = today.getFullYear(); 
   
   //alert(local[today.getDay()]);
 alert(tahun);
   //$('#wordsdate').val(local[today.getDay()]);


});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="choose date" id="getdate" />
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="datepicker date" id="datenum" disabled/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="wordsdate" id="wordsdate" disabled/>
  </div>
```

example :
let say we choose a date : 05/06/2014
then result on textfield : the fifth of June Two thousand and fourteen

Comment: Closed duplicate: [SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function argument (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40912413/4642212). Don’t use `1=>` in JavaScript. That’s PHP syntax.

Comment: @Xufox: thanks for the link that u gave, i just checked its doesnt explain how to assign value to key in jquery

Comment: If you want something like an associative array in JS, use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Lang = ['java','asp','c#']; , lang [1] = java; is this right ?

Comment: No, [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) are zero-based.

Comment: so its mean we cannot change index key in js ?

Comment: Again, you’d need to use an object for that or include some meaningless element as the first element of an array. There’s absolutely no reason to do this, however. Why do you need a 1-based array?!

Comment: as we know amount of month is 1 - 12 , key index in array 0 -11,  datepiker cannot defined januari as 0.

Comment: The JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) also has zero-based months. January is month 0 and December is month 11. If your month is 1-based you can simply subtract 1 from your index, e.g. `var monthValue = 1; var monthString = bulan[monthValue - 1];`.

Comment: then why if i set a date on datepiker , always returning previsious month, jan will be dec, feb will be jan and so on..

Comment: danke sir, i see the light now , as simple as that, seem datepicker using zero based array, while my local month use 0 based.so in this it should be today.getMonth()+1; Und es ist Arbeit, danke euch nochmal